Error: In azure machine learning workspace autosuggestion only works for the first operation on the raw data, the serial operations don't work
Image of my workspace
Since all the modules are connected serially, I was expecting all the operations I'm doing on the data serially, one after the other. But the autosuggest doesn't work, which is very problematic now. I'm new to azure, I just don't get it

what do you mean by autosuggest, what are you expecting? please add more details.
